# Suggestions for temporary fix with controller.php ($cachable = false, $urlparams = [])

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5

I'm looking for a possible quick fix (temporary) for the follow error. This is on a Joomla 3 site, which I can only seem to assume was migrated from a Joomla 2.5 site which hopefully will be migrated soon. Pending customer agreement.

> Fatal error: Declaration of
> Dynamic_contentController::display($cachable = false) must be
> compatible with
> Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController::display($cachable = false,
> $urlparams = []) in
> /home/customer/www/clariumfcs.com/public_html/administrator/components/com_dynamic_content/controller.php
> on line 32

The error is referring to the following piece of code:

```
/**
 * Method to display a view.
 *
 * @param   boolean         If true, the view output will be cached
 * @param   array           An array of safe url parameters and their variable types, for valid values see {@link JFilterInput::clean()}.
 *
 * @return  JController     This object to support chaining.
 * @since   1.5
 */
public function display($cachable = false)
{
    require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/admin.php';

    DC_AdminHelper::addSubmenu(JRequest::getVar('view'));

    $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addStylesheet('components/com_dynamic_content/assets/admin.css');
    $document->addScript('components/com_dynamic_content/assets/jquery-1.7.2.js');
    $document->addScript('components/com_dynamic_content/assets/admin.js');

    JRequest::setVar('view', JRequest::getCmd('view', 'Dynamic_contents'));
    
    parent::display($cachable);
}
```

I've completed the initial google search for the error but come up empty and this isn't really something I'm familiar with. I'm guessing function an additional parameter? Would I be on the correct path with that? I'm stumped. If there is an easy edit for this function I'd appreciate it so I can access the component temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to replace the line

```
public function display($cachable = false)
```

with this line

```
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = array())
```

which defines the display method in `libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php`

Essentially two parameters are available in the default function where as in your function only one is provided and the message is saying you need provide the second one, in this case and array called `$urlparams`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. That has allowed us to access the details in the background which makes it a lot easier to move the information to another component.